# insert variable value to custom field using in salesforce

Tags: apex

I am trying to assign value of j to custom field Amount__c can anyone help me..!

```
Integer i=0;
Double j=0.0;
List<Received_Amount__c> ReceivedName = [
        Select Name,
          Amount__c
        From Received_Amount__c
        Where Flat__r.Sold__c = true];

for(i=0; i<ReceivedName.size(); i++) {
    j=j+ReceivedName[i].Amount__c;
    // j=i;
}

if(j>0) {
    Received_Amount__c uu = new Received_Amount__c();
  uu.Amount__c = j;
  insert uu;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sum the amounts using a loop like this (or an [aggregate query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm)):

```
Decimal total = 0;
for (Received_Amount__c ra : [
        Select Amount__c
        From Received_Amount__c
        Where Flat__r.Sold__c = true
        And Amount__c != null
        ]) {
    total += ra.Amount__c;
}
```

But then to store the value, you need a table (SObject) to store the value into as well as a column (SObject field). For a situation like this, you would usually be storing the total in a different SObject:

```
Total_Amount__c t = new Total_Amount__c(Amount__c = total);
insert t;
```

But note that there are other approaches to this problem, such as the built-in [rollup summary fields](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/point_click_business_logic/roll_up_summary_fields), that might be a better choice.